# Dynamically list data in dynamic repeater (Asp.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project, i've been trying something for a while. User must select the Group from select. This Add button runs asp repeater so i can list groups. There are 2 button in group line. Right one delets the group and left one opens dynamic divs. (As you can see) There are some Javascript works so i set the id's dynamically. **It's ok until here.** Now, if the user want to check fixed questions, i need to show the questions that in that group. And user must be able to add question under the group dynamically. I tryed to use GridView but i couldnt handle. So any advice?

Here is what i want to do:[image]

```
<ul>
     <asp:Repeater ID="GroupRepeater" runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate>                 
             <li class="groupli">
                 <div style="width:100%; float:left; margin-top:2%;">
                     <h3 style="display:block; float:left; width:auto;"><%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>.<%# Eval("QuestGroup")%></h3>                         
                 <asp:Button CssClass="GroupLiButtonD" OnClick="RemoveGroup" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuestGroup") %>' ID="DeleteGroupBtn" runat="server"/>                     
                 <button type="button" onclick="ShowQuestArea('<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>_div')" class="GroupLiButtonA"></button> 
                 </div>
                 <div id='<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>_div' style="width:100%; margin-left:3%; float:left; display:none;">
                     <div class="questarea"> 
                         <div style="width:100%; margin-top:1%;">
                             <h4 style="display:block; float:left; width:200px;">Add Fixed Question</h4>                                
                             <input name='check_<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>' id='fixcheck_<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>' onchange="FixedCheck('fixcheck_<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>','<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>')" type="radio" />
                         </div> 
                         <div id="fixarea_<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>" class="subarea"> <%--fixedquestion view start tag--%>

                         </div>  <%--fixedquestion view end tag--%>                          
                         <div style="width:100%; margin-top:1%;">
                             <h4 style="display:block; float:left; width:200px;">Add Random Question</h4>
                         <input name='check_<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>' id='randomcheck_<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>' onchange="RandomCheck('randomcheck_<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>','<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>')" type="radio" />
                             <div id="randomarea_<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>" class="subarea">
                                 <div style="margin-top:1%;">
                                     <p style="color:black; float:left;">Number of Random Questions:</p><input type="number" max="20" min="0" style="width:20px; float:left;" />
                                     <button>Add</button>
                                 </div>                                 
                             </div>
                         </div>                        
                 </div>                         
                     </div>                                                                                 
              </li>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
         </ul
```

> My code might seem complicated. I added an image. So you can ignore my code for giving advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit of jquery and some ajax calls will do the trick.

You can add same **class**  and a **data-groupid** attribute to the "fixed answer" radio buttons.

*Lets say the id of the  group questions is **resultlist** and it is a ul  element.*

Then you will handle the click to load the questions with ajax

```
$(".yourclass").on"click", function (e) { 
    var groupid=$(this).data("groupid");
    //get the questions
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=iso-8859-7",
       url: 'yourpage.aspx/yourmethod',
       data: "{'group':'" + groupid +"'}",
       async: false,
       error: function (xhr) {console.log(xhr.responseText);},
       success: function (response) {
              //Query the jQuery object for the values
              var items = response.d;
              if (items == null) {
                $('#resultlist').empty();
                $('#resultlist').append("<li> no questions... </li>");
              }
              else {
                var fragment = "";
                $.each(items, function (index, val) {
                var theQuestion = val.theQuestion;
                var theCode = val.theCode;
                fragment += "<li data-qustionid='"+theCode+"' class='question'>"+theQuestion+"</li>";});
                $('#resultlist').empty();
                $("#resultlist").append(fragment);
              }
     });

  });
```

in your .cs file you will add a new web method that will get the group's questions

```
[WebMethod]
  public static List<Results> yourmethod(string text, string phone, string type)
        {
            List<Results> result = new List<Results>();
            DataTable question = getQuestions();
          if(question!=null){
            foreach (DataRow rw in autocomlete.Rows)
            {
              result.Add(new Results { theQuestion = rw[0].ToString(), 
              theCode = rw[3].ToString() });
            }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

and likewise you will handle the click of the class **question** which on click will get the data-questionid and update it to the database. You can add more fields that you need in the data- attributes ([link here](https://api.jquery.com/data/)) Readmore for ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)